PgWeb Container not started when deployed to azure
I have an .net aspire application and want to use PgWeb to access my postgres DB. That seems to work fine locally:

but when I deploy with azd up I can't see any container or entry for pgweb.

My setup in the AppHost looks like this:
var db = builder.AddPostgres("postgresql")
.WithPgWeb()
.AddDatabase("db");

You'll have to explicitly configure the PgWeb resource to be deployed and accessible:
.WithPgWeb(x => x
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints()
    .PublishAsContainer());

